# Redirecting an "HTTPS" to "HTTP" on Microsoft IIS

Tags: ssl, redirect, https, certificate

I have a website thats currently being accessed on an "https" url but the certificate is expiring soon and we do not want SSL on this website anymore so just an "http" access is fine. How do I get the requests made to https url automatically redirect to the http url? This page might have been bookmarked by people and the bookmark will still have the "https" url. I want these requests to be redirected to the "http" url. I am running my website on a Microsoft IIS.

Comment: If you automatically redirect, users will never change the bookmark and you're stuck forever.

Answer (score 0):

Reply to the request with an HTTP 301: [Moved Permanently](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar scenario, but in the opposite direction.

set your DNS Manager to point to same ip/machine for both http and https

on the iis machine, create a dummy web site for https that points it to http.